# opening mp3 player in new window rather than new tab?

Tags: javascript, html, window

I've embedded the Yahoo! player into my website to play MP3's that my users upload, but the issue I am having is whenever I try to open in a new window it always opens in a new tab. I've searched this site and google for a good 10 minutes and all i'm seeing is "you can't make it happen" I know that isn't true because I use plenty of sites that manage to open up new windows. If anyone knows how to do this it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you try use `window.open()` in js?

Comment: @LeeB: can you post some code. Like ant_Ti said did you try window.open?

Comment: I don't need to post code, i'm asking how to open a new window. I have no code as I don't know HOW to open in a new window. And yes i've tried window.open() but it just opens in a new tab rather than a new window.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using [this method](http://webplayer.yahoo.com/get/#_) form their site, meaning you have html links to the content you want to play. 
How about using the **target="_blank"** property in your html

```
<a href="http://www.mymusic.com/mysong.mp3" target="_blank">Song</a>
```

Comment: I've managed to solve the issue using the Javascript pop up window, then stored the player within that. It's not tidy, but for now, it does the job until i can find an alternative. Thanks though.